# how to select checkbox in a dropdown lists

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate some selenium case in python, for the following special case, my current code does not work. As we could see from the following UI. In the first page, there is a "Client Interfaces" section, and it is meant to select from the dropdown list.

[image]

And when user is to click the dropdown list, it is listing bunch of checkboxes, where user needs to make further selections.

[image]

Now here is my code:

```
  dropdwon_xpath = "..."                                                                                                           
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, dropdown_xpath))).click()

  # The XPATH of "Client Interfaces"  is:  ".../div/div[1]/div"
  # The XPATH of the lte1 checkbox    is:  ".../div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/label"
  # And here is my customized XPAH of lte1 bases on the location of "Client Interfaces".    
  lte1_checkbox = "//div[.='Client Interfaces']/ancestor::div[1]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input"
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, lte1_checkbox ))).click()
```

But it never works. During the runtime, I do see the dropdown happens, but it did not do any further selection on those checkboxes.  Any suggestions what I could try ?

Thanks,

Chun

Here is the screenshot of the html layout for this area:
[image]

Comment: What website and html element is it?

Comment: This is not from the public website, and I am trying it on Chrome.

Comment: Ancestor is pretty much never used we use element you want so a div with child element div with text would start   //div[.//div[.='Client Interfaces']] and so forth.

Comment: Can you provide the html structure

Comment: I have just added in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing input with label sometimes the actions happen with that instead.

Comment: //div[@class='col-4'][.//div[.='Client Interfaces']]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input would be more appropriate if you want a child element with text inside a parent tag.

Comment: Hi. I have posted what I have found by using yours. It is not the answer, but more inputs. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer yet, and I just want to give extra inputs for what I have found.

I have tried the xpath Arundeep Chohan suggested as such:

```
//div[@class='col-4'][.//div[.='Client Interfaces']]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input
```

and the issue stays. I believe both of Arundeep's and mine should be working. And I have purposely tried following code to check at what point it become "invisible" during the execution time.

```
BY = By.XPATH
point1 = "//div[@class='col-4'][.//div[.='Client Interfaces']]/following-sibling::div[1]"
point2 = "//div[@class='col-4'][.//div[.='Client Interfaces']]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[2]"
point3 = "//div[@class='col-4'][.//div[.='Client Interfaces']]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[2]/div[1]"
point4 = "//div[@class='col-4'][.//div[.='Client Interfaces']]/following-sibling::div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input"

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((BY,point1))).is_displayed()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((BY,point2))).is_displayed()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((BY,point3))).is_displayed()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((BY,point4))).is_displayed()
```

What I have found is, point1 still visible, but since point2, it becomes "invisible", although the dropdown already happened. And I guess that is why my original script is kind of "disoriented". Those "div[2]/div[1]/div/input" are actually from those checkbox pieces after the dropdown happens.

Thanks,

Chun